# What is the scope of "values" in SPARQL query graph

Tags: sparql

I have a query that includes many subqueries, which also include some subqueries. I want to know the scope of the values clause in a SPARQL query. Does it go down to the subqueries as well?

If I defined a values clause in the subquery, and used the same variable in a father query, will that variable have just the values specified in the son query? (what about vice versa?)

I looked at the [SPARQL 1.1 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#inline-data-syntax), but all I found is the following, which doesn't appear to answer my question:

> A VALUES block of data can appear in a query pattern or at the end of a SELECT query, including a subquery.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SPARQL subqueries are evaluated from the innermost to the outermost.  A **values** block in an outer query isn't available to the inner queries.  As an example:

```sql
select ?x ?y ?z {
  values ?x { "x" }

  { select (?x as ?y) ("z" as ?z) {} }
}
```

```
-----------------
| x   | y | z   |
=================
| "x" |   | "z" |
-----------------
```

If the value of **?x** had been available in the inner query, then **?y** would have the value "x", but it doesn't.

On the other hand, bindings from a **values** block in a subquery can be passed outward, *if* they are selected. For instance, in this query, the subquery binds **?x** and **?y**, but only projects **?x**:

```sql
select ?x ?y {
  {
    select ?x {
      values ?x { "x" }
      values ?y { "y" }
    }
  }
}
```

```
-----------
| x   | y |
===========
| "x" |   |
-----------
```

The official answer is in the spec, but not in the part about **values**.  It's in [18.2.1 Variable Scope](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#variableScope).  It's not the easiest table to follow, but the thing to note is rules like:

> Group { P1 P2 … } : v is in-scope if it is in-scope in one or more of P1, P2, …

which means that the set of in-scope variables for a pattern `{ ... }` is defined as the union of the in-scope variables of the things that appear within in.  Variables get "passed" outward to the their enclosing forms, not the other way around.

There's one exception to that, I think, which is a **values** block that's outside the outermost query, which, I think, is pretty much the same as a **values** block inside the outermost query:

```sql
select ?x ?y ?yy {
  { select (?y as ?yy) {} }
}
values (?x ?y) { (1 2) }
```

```
--------------
| x | y | yy |
==============
| 1 | 2 |    |
--------------
```